# Unity RewardedVideoAds not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, rewardedvideoad

Hello I am trying to implement Admob with unity, I have successfully integrated banner ads and Interstitial ads using the Test ids provided by Admob over here https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads. How ever I am unable to display any rewarded Video ads. When ever I call the RewardedVidosAds nothing shows up and a debug log error displays Ad not ready. This is the following code I am using:

```js
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdManager: MonoBehaviour {

  public RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideoAd;
  private InterstitialAd fullAdmob;

  private bool rewardBasedEventHandlersSet = false;
  // reward initialized
  public int scoreAmount = 100;

  // Use this for initialization

  void Start() {
    //loading both rewarded and interstitial ads in start.
    LoadRewardBasedAd();
    //RequestFull ();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update() {

  }

  public void LoadRewardBasedAd() {

    rewardBasedVideoAd = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

    //Test
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
      .Build();

    rewardBasedVideoAd.LoadAd(adRequest, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");


  }





  public void ShowRewardBasedAd() {

    if (rewardBasedVideoAd.IsLoaded()) {
      Debug.Log("Showiung video");
      rewardBasedVideoAd.Show();
    } else Debug.Log("not ready");

  }

}
```

I have not currently mediated my video Ads could this be causing the problem? I read that you dont need to mediate your ads if your using a test AdId. I also get the following errors in my logcat when calling for a rewardedVideoAd

Fail to instantiate adapter com.google.DummyAdapter
Fail to load ad:3